# Which open source LDAP directory server should I use?

Tags: ldap

This is an internal directory for a small (60 employees) company.
I'm stuck between OpenDS and ApacheDS. Any recommendations? I'm pretty worried that oracle will kill off OpenDS development.

Comment: Why not OpenLDAP?

Answer (score 3):

OpenLDAP that even comes with [an O'Reilly Book on it](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565924918).

Answer (score 2):

Keep using OpenDS. It's the best, the easiest to use. Should you be worry about the fate of the project, be aware that ForgeRock has stepped in, offering support for OpenDS through the OpenDJ product and project. OpenDJ is a downstream project of OpenDS, developed fully in open source. Check on ForgeRock website, for downloads, source code and more...

Answer (score 0):

If you need Windows-interoperability then maybe [389DS](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/) has some useful features.

Answer (score 0):

Do'nt worry. Oracle may Kill -9 OpenDS, ApacheDS will still be around ;)

And it's really open source, so what else ?